# Is it possible to parse all public variables of an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, parsing, object, types, public

Imagine I have an object with a set of public variables and private ones

```
function myObj()
{
    var private1 = 1;
    var private2 = 2;
    this.func = function(){console.log('anything');};
    this.public1 = 3;
    this.public2 = '4';
}
```

Is there a way to create a function that can parse the object and retrieve the name, value and type of the public variables.

The prototype of this function would be :

```
parseObj(object)
```

The console result would be :

```
>object has public1 with value 3 of type Number
>object has public2 with value 4 of type String
```

Comment: `var keys = Object.keys(obj);`? + `typeof`.

Comment: Javascript really doesn't care much about types. You will notice that all of those objects were initialized as vars. Why do you need to know the types?

Comment: Oh type is needed in what I want to do. I want to generate particular html tags depending on types

Comment: @zerkms can you write that as an answer if it's one thx ;) .

Comment: It's not an answer, those are just keywords for your own research.

Comment: ok well thank you then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quite easily make such a function using *for in loop*:

```js
function parseObj(object) {
    for(var name in object) {
        if(object.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            // ignoring methods
            if(typeof object[name] !== 'function') {
                console.log('object has '+name+' with value '+object[name]+' of type '+typeof object[name]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem without having to use es6 features.

Comment: The value returned by [*typeof*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator) does not accurately reflect a value's [*type*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values), e.g.  `typeof Null` returns "object", but its type is *Null*.

Comment: @RobG, sure, but it's a bug in javascript, not in my code. If it's really that important to you, you can make a `function getTypeOf(val) { return (val===null) ? 'null' : typeof val; }` and use it in my code.

Comment: It's no my problem but the OP's: "*retrieve the … type of the public variables*".

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Object.entries(object).forEach((prop) => {
  const [name, value] = prop;
  console.log(`object has ${name} with value of ${value} and type ${typeof(value)}`)
})
```

I get this in console:

```
// object has func with value of function (){console.log('anything');} and type function
// object has public1 with value of 3 and type number
// object has public2 with value of 4 and type string
```

Comment: that's es6 features!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include the "not ECMAScript 2015" condition in the OP. If ECMAScript 5.1 is OK, then *Object.keys* will return own properties (there's a [polyfill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill)).

There is no built-in function that accurately returns a value's Type (though you could do this yourself fairly easily). *typeof* returns values that are helpful but do not match types, e.g. there is no "function" type but:

```
typeof function(){}
```

returns "function". Also, host objects may return various values (e.g. "unknown").

```js
function myObj()
{
    var private1 = 1;
    var private2 = 2;
    this.func = function(){console.log('anything');};
    this.public1 = 3;
    this.public2 = '4';
}

var obj = new myObj();

function showProps(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log('object has ' + key + ' with value ' + obj[key] +
                ' with typeof ' + (typeof obj[key]));
  });
}

showProps(obj);
```